# Misaligned <td> in the same row inside <pre><code>

Tags: html, css

I'm having troubles with some CSS issues with my blog, which is based on Cayman Theme.

The problem I am having is that, after enabling line numbers with Jekyll, the code blocks have gone severely misaligned, as you can see in the following image.

> [image: before]

My target is to make it look like this:

> [image: after]

I noticed in Developer Console, that the code block is rendering badly because of an extra code block:

[image: show]

Here's a minimal code for you to produce the first image.

```css
.main-content {
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
    overflow-wrap: break-word !important;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
    max-width: 64rem;
    padding: 3rem 6rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    margin: 0 auto 3rem;
    border-radius: 4rem;
}

.main-content :first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.main-content code {
    padding: 2px 4px;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    color: #567482;
    background-color: #f3f6fa;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
}

.main-content pre:not(.highlight) {
    max-height: 30rem;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    font: 0.95em monospace;
    color: #567482;
    word-wrap: normal;
    background-color: #f3f6fa;
    border: solid 1px #dcf0e6;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    padding: 0.8rem;
    overflow: auto;
    line-height: 1.45;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.main-content pre:not(.highlight) > code {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: inherit;
    color: #567482;
    word-break: normal;
    white-space: pre;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
}

.main-content .highlight {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.main-content .highlight pre:not(.highlight) {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    word-break: normal;
    padding: 0.8rem;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    line-height: 1.45;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.main-content pre code {
    display: inline;
    max-width: initial;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: initial;
    line-height: inherit;
    word-wrap: normal;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
}

.main-content table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.main-content .highlight table th, .main-content .highlight table td {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #606c71;
    background-color: #15CC57;
    background-image: /*url("https://ibug.github.io/image/bg.jpg"), */ linear-gradient(120deg, #155799, #15CC57);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Title title title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#159A34">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="main-content blog-post">
        <div class="language-vb highlighter-rouge">
          <div class="highlight"><pre class="highlight"><code>
            <table class="rouge-table"><tbody><tr><td class="rouge-gutter gl"><pre class="lineno">1
2
3
4
</pre>
  </td>
  <td class="rouge-code">
    <pre><span class="n">asdfghjkl</span>
<span class="n">asdfghjkl</span>
<span class="n">asdfghjkl</span>
<span class="n">asdfghjkl</span>
</pre>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</code></pre>
</div>
</div>
</section>
</body></html>
```

**Special Requirement**: Since the HTML is generated by Jekyll, it's not convenient for me to change it. I need pure CSS tweaks.

**Note**: Because I have very little CSS knowledge, the above file is created by reducing code from the real page. I tried to cut off everything unnecessary, but I'm not confident it's the bare minimal.

Comment: The main problem for us to help, is that the code you posted doesn't render the same issue as the screen shot does. If that mean you need to add some more code so it does, then do.

Comment: @LGSon Sorry! I didn't realize that the rendered result could change after beautifying HTML. I've put the original code in and it should render properly. Thanks very much!

Comment: Great. I see you figured it out. Best possible, as when one does, one learn one more thing :)

Answer (score 3):

The existing answers made a great hint, and I am surprised to figure out that the best answer being so simple:

```css
pre.highlight {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

The whitespaces in `<pre class="highlight">` no longer "stacks" and creates a lot of blank area.

```css
.main-content {
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
    overflow-wrap: break-word !important;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
    max-width: 64rem;
    padding: 3rem 6rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    margin: 0 auto 3rem;
    border-radius: 4rem;
}

.main-content :first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.main-content code {
    padding: 2px 4px;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    color: #567482;
    background-color: #f3f6fa;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
}

.main-content pre:not(.highlight) {
    max-height: 30rem;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    font: 0.95em monospace;
    color: #567482;
    word-wrap: normal;
    background-color: #f3f6fa;
    border: solid 1px #dcf0e6;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    padding: 0.8rem;
    overflow: auto;
    line-height: 1.45;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.main-content pre:not(.highlight) > code {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: inherit;
    color: #567482;
    word-break: normal;
    white-space: pre;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
}

.main-content .highlight {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.main-content .highlight pre:not(.highlight) {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    word-break: normal;
    padding: 0.8rem;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    line-height: 1.45;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.main-content pre code {
    display: inline;
    max-width: initial;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: initial;
    line-height: inherit;
    word-wrap: normal;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
}

.main-content table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.main-content .highlight table th, .main-content .highlight table td {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #606c71;
    background-color: #15CC57;
    background-image: /*url("https://ibug.github.io/image/bg.jpg"), */ linear-gradient(120deg, #155799, #15CC57);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
}

pre.highlight {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Title title title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#159A34">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="main-content blog-post">
        <div class="language-vb highlighter-rouge">
          <div class="highlight"><pre class="highlight"><code>
            <table class="rouge-table"><tbody><tr><td class="rouge-gutter gl"><pre class="lineno">1
2
3
4
</pre>
  </td>
  <td class="rouge-code">
    <pre><span class="n">asdfghjkl</span>
<span class="n">asdfghjkl</span>
<span class="n">asdfghjkl</span>
<span class="n">asdfghjkl</span>
</pre>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</code></pre>
</div>
</div>
</section>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in the `<pre>` HTML tag. I know you said that it is not convenient to you change the HTML but can you give it a try and remove that tag?
Or atleast format your HTML? See my solution..

> The `<pre>` tag defines preformatted text.
>   Text in a `<pre>` element is displayed in a fixed-width font (usually Courier), and it preserves both spaces and line breaks.
>   https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

```css
.main-content {
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
    overflow-wrap: break-word !important;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
    max-width: 64rem;
    padding: 3rem 6rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    margin: 0 auto 3rem;
    border-radius: 4rem;
}

.main-content :first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.main-content code {
    padding: 2px 4px;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    color: #567482;
    background-color: #f3f6fa;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
}

.main-content pre:not(.highlight) {
    max-height: 30rem;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    font: 0.95em monospace;
    color: #567482;
    word-wrap: normal;
    background-color: #f3f6fa;
    border: solid 1px #dcf0e6;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    padding: 0.8rem;
    overflow: auto;
    line-height: 1.45;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.main-content pre:not(.highlight) > code {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: inherit;
    color: #567482;
    word-break: normal;
    white-space: pre;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
}

.main-content .highlight {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.main-content .highlight pre:not(.highlight) {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    word-break: normal;
    padding: 0.8rem;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    line-height: 1.45;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.main-content pre code {
    display: inline;
    max-width: initial;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: initial;
    line-height: inherit;
    word-wrap: normal;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
}

.main-content table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.main-content .highlight table th, .main-content .highlight table td {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #606c71;
    background-color: #15CC57;
    background-image: /*url("https://ibug.github.io/image/bg.jpg"), */ linear-gradient(120deg, #155799, #15CC57);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
}

.gl:before{
    content:"\a\a";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Title title title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#159A34">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="main-content blog-post">
        <div class="language-vb highlighter-rouge">
          <div class="highlight"><pre class="highlight"><code>
            <table class="rouge-table"><tbody><tr><td class="rouge-gutter gl"><pre class="lineno">1
2
3
4
</pre>
  </td>
  <td class="rouge-code">
    <pre><span class="n">asdfghjkl</span>
<span class="n">asdfghjkl</span>
<span class="n">asdfghjkl</span>
<span class="n">asdfghjkl</span>
</pre>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</code></pre>
</div>
</div>
</section>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to patch the <pre> element with CSS? Because it's generated by Jekyll, I have to write complex scripts to remove such tags. It's better to leave the HTML intact.

Comment: @iBug see the edited snippet. I added this css .gl:before{
    content:"\a\a";
    white-space: pre;
}

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `code` and `pre` tags that surround the `table`. Because of that the html is also invalid, because `table` is not allowed in `code` nor in `pre`.  If you remove those tags, the output will be fine. I'm sure it's possible to edit the Jekyll templates to make sure those tags will no longer be present.

```css
.main-content {
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
    overflow-wrap: break-word !important;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
    max-width: 64rem;
    padding: 3rem 6rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    margin: 0 auto 3rem;
    border-radius: 4rem;
}

.main-content :first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.main-content code {
    padding: 2px 4px;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    color: #567482;
    background-color: #f3f6fa;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
}

.main-content pre:not(.highlight) {
    max-height: 30rem;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    font: 0.95em monospace;
    color: #567482;
    word-wrap: normal;
    background-color: #f3f6fa;
    border: solid 1px #dcf0e6;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    padding: 0.8rem;
    overflow: auto;
    line-height: 1.45;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.main-content pre:not(.highlight) > code {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: inherit;
    color: #567482;
    word-break: normal;
    white-space: pre;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
}

.main-content .highlight {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.main-content .highlight pre:not(.highlight) {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    word-break: normal;
    padding: 0.8rem;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    line-height: 1.45;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.main-content pre code {
    display: inline;
    max-width: initial;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: initial;
    line-height: inherit;
    word-wrap: normal;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
}

.main-content table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.main-content .highlight table th, .main-content .highlight table td {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #606c71;
    background-color: #15CC57;
    background-image: /*url("https://ibug.github.io/image/bg.jpg"), */ linear-gradient(120deg, #155799, #15CC57);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Title title title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#159A34">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="main-content blog-post">
        <div class="language-vb highlighter-rouge">
          <div class="highlight">
            <table class="rouge-table"><tbody><tr><td class="rouge-gutter gl"><pre class="lineno">1
2
3
4
</pre>
  </td>
  <td class="rouge-code">
    <pre><span class="n">asdfghjkl</span>
<span class="n">asdfghjkl</span>
<span class="n">asdfghjkl</span>
<span class="n">asdfghjkl</span>
</pre>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</section>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done by css. You have to at-least change the indentation of your HTML code. Try removing indentation from each line inside `<pre class="highlight">` like this:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #606c71;
    background-color: #15CC57;
    background-image: /*url("https://ibug.github.io/image/bg.jpg"), */ linear-gradient(120deg, #155799, #15CC57);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
}

.main-content {
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
    overflow-wrap: break-word !important;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
    max-width: 64rem;
    padding: 3rem 6rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    margin: 0 auto 3rem;
    border-radius: 4rem;
}

.main-content :first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.main-content code {
    padding: 2px 4px;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    color: #567482;
    background-color: #f3f6fa;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
}

.main-content pre:not(.highlight) {
    max-height: 30rem;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    font: 0.95em monospace;
    color: #567482;
    word-wrap: normal;
    background-color: #f3f6fa;
    border: solid 1px #dcf0e6;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    padding: 0.8rem;
    overflow: auto;
    line-height: 1.45;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.main-content pre:not(.highlight) > code {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: inherit;
    color: #567482;
    word-break: normal;
    white-space: pre;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
}

.main-content .highlight {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.main-content .highlight pre:not(.highlight) {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    word-break: normal;
    padding: 0.8rem;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    line-height: 1.45;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.main-content pre code {
    display: inline;
    max-width: initial;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: initial;
    line-height: inherit;
    word-wrap: normal;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
}

.main-content table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.main-content .highlight table th, .main-content .highlight table td {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Title title title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#159A34">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="main-content blog-post">
      <div class="language-vb highlighter-rouge">
        <div class="highlight">
          <pre class="highlight">
<!-- Removing indentation start -->
<code>
<table class="rouge-table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="rouge-gutter gl">
<pre class="lineno">
1
2
3
4
</pre>
</td>
<td class="rouge-code">
<pre>
<span class="n">asdfghjkl</span>
<span class="n">asdfghjkl</span>
<span class="n">asdfghjkl</span>
<span class="n">asdfghjkl</span>
</pre>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</code>
<!-- Removing indentation end -->
          </pre>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body></html>
```